# How can we display both label and value on a pieSliceText on an 3d pie chart using google charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, angular6

Iam using Google Chart in Angular 6

I am using

`pieSliceText: 'value'`

But I need to display both label and value on the pie slice,

I tried using 
`pieSliceText: 'label-and-value'`

similar to

`pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage'`

But this doesnt work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a couple options...

---

1) use the following option to label the slices...

```
legend: {
  position: 'labeled'
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    is3D: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'labeled'
    },
    pieSliceText: 'value'    
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart_3d"></div>
```

---

2) use the following option to display the value of the slice...

```
pieSliceText: 'value'
```

with the above option, the slice will display the formatted value by default.
using object notation, we can provide both the value `v:` and formatted value `f:` in the data table.

```
{v: 11, f: 'Work: 11'}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', {v: 11, f: 'Work: 11'}],
    ['Eat', {v: 11, f: 'Eat: 2'}],
    ['Commute', {v: 11, f: 'Commute: 2'}],
    ['Watch TV', {v: 11, f: 'Watch TV: 2'}],
    ['Sleep', {v: 11, f: 'Sleep: 7'}]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 12,
      left: 12,
      right: 12,
      bottom: 12
    },
    height: 400,
    is3D: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    pieSliceText: 'value'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart_3d"></div>
```

Comment: this works for me , but i have to display them in two lines label followed by the value and '/n' doesnt work here.

Comment: or can we control the text displayed in the legend when the legend is set to labelled ...?

Comment: on the latter, you can add option `pieSliceText: 'value' ` with `'labeled'` to show the value on the slice, instead of showing percentage twice. changed first snippet above...

Comment: on the prior, you can add your custom labels during the chart's `'ready'` event, but if your slices do not all have different values, you won't be able to determine which value goes with which label...